# How can I debug something inside a dll after a $.get?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, dll, breakpoints

I am working on a solution that makes a `$.get` call to a controller (in a different solution in a different module) inside of a dll. How can I put a break point in the original code of the external project, and actually hit that break point?

Please explain this like you were explaining it to a six year old because im still pretty new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure Visual Studio is attached to your server process.  (if you hit F5, it will be)
- Click Debug, Modules, and make sure symbols are loaded for the other DLL.
  If they aren't, right-click it, Load Symbols
- Open the original source file.
- Set a breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks that worked, but I would still like to add that for it to work you have to open the original source file inside of your current solution. It seems my issue was happening because i was opening it in a different visual studio

Comment: @Bryand: You could also attach the other VS instance to your process.